# how to resolve the error : HttpClientErrorException: 400 null?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, web-services, spring-mvc

I developed a rest service which manages the crud operations which concern customers.

Now I would like to call my service rest from my spring mvc application, but I get the following error when I click on the "update" button which is in my jsp page:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is
  org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 null
  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
  org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) cause mère
    org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 null
    org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94)
    org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79)
    org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:766)
    org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:724)
    org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:680)
    org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:332)
    com.luv2code.springdemo.service.CustomerServiceRestClientImpl.getCustomer(CustomerServiceRestClientImpl.java:59)
    com.luv2code.springdemo.controller.CustomerController.showFormForUpdate(CustomerController.java:62)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

this is my DemoAppConfig class :

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.luv2code.springdemo")
@PropertySource({ "classpath:application.properties" })
public class DemoAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    // define a bean for ViewResolver

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

    // define bean for RestTemplate ... this is used to make client REST calls

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    // add resource handler for loading css, images, etc

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
          .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
          .addResourceLocations("/resources/"); 
    }   
}
```

and this is my file application.properties :

```
#
# The URL for the CRM REST API
# - update to match your local environment
#
crm.rest.url=http://localhost:8080/spring-crm-rest/api/customers
```

and this is my service class :

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.luv2code.springdemo.model.Customer;

@Service
public class CustomerServiceRestClientImpl implements CustomerService {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private String crmRestUrl;

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    @Autowired
    public CustomerServiceRestClientImpl(RestTemplate theRestTemplate, 
                                        @Value("${crm.rest.url}") String theUrl) {
        restTemplate = theRestTemplate;
        crmRestUrl = theUrl;

        logger.info("Loaded property:  crm.rest.url=" + crmRestUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {

        logger.info("in getCustomers(): Calling REST API " + crmRestUrl);

        // make REST call
        ResponseEntity<List<Customer>> responseEntity = 
                                            restTemplate.exchange(crmRestUrl, HttpMethod.GET, null, 
                                                                  new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Customer>>() {});

        // get the list of customers from response
        List<Customer> customers = responseEntity.getBody();

        logger.info("in getCustomers(): customers" + customers);

        return customers;
    }

    @Override
    public Customer getCustomer(int theId) {

        logger.info("in getCustomer(): Calling REST API " + crmRestUrl);

        // make REST call
        Customer theCustomer = 
                restTemplate.getForObject(crmRestUrl + "/" + theId, 
                                          Customer.class);

        logger.info("in saveCustomer(): theCustomer=" + theCustomer);

        return theCustomer;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveCustomer(Customer theCustomer) {

        logger.info("in saveCustomer(): Calling REST API " + crmRestUrl);

        int employeeId = theCustomer.getId();

        // make REST call
        if (employeeId == 0) {
            // add employee
            restTemplate.postForEntity(crmRestUrl, theCustomer, String.class);          

        } else {
            // update employee
            restTemplate.put(crmRestUrl, theCustomer);
        }

        logger.info("in saveCustomer(): success");  
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteCustomer(int theId) {

        logger.info("in deleteCustomer(): Calling REST API " + crmRestUrl);

        // make REST call
        restTemplate.delete(crmRestUrl + "/" + theId);

        logger.info("in deleteCustomer(): deleted customer theId=" + theId);
    }

}
```

and this is my controller which is in my rest service :

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.rest;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.luv2code.springdemo.entity.Customer;
import com.luv2code.springdemo.service.CustomerService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class CustomerRestController {


    // importer la depende du service

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;

    // ajout de la methode qui permet de récupérer les customers (clients)

    @GetMapping("/customers")
    public List<Customer> getCustomers(){


        return customerService.getCustomers();
    }


    // récupérer un seul customer avec un id donné en parametre

    @GetMapping("/customer/{customerId}")
    public Customer getCustomer(@PathVariable int customerId) {

        Customer theCustomer = customerService.getCustomer(customerId);

        if(theCustomer == null) {
            throw new CustomerNotFoundException("Le client avec l'id :"+ customerId + " n'est pas trouvé");
        }


        return theCustomer;
    }

    // ajouter la méthode d'ajout d'un nouveau customer

    @PostMapping("/customers")
    public Customer addCustomer(@RequestBody  Customer theCustomer) {

        theCustomer.setId(0);

        customerService.saveCustomer(theCustomer);

        return theCustomer;
    }


    // modification d'un customer existent :

    @PutMapping("/customers")
    public Customer updateCustomer(@RequestBody  Customer theCustomer) {



        customerService.saveCustomer(theCustomer);

        return theCustomer;
    }

    // delete un customer en fonction de l'id donné :

    @DeleteMapping("/customers/{customerId}")
    public String DeleteCustomer(@PathVariable int customerId) {

        Customer theCustomer = customerService.getCustomer(customerId);

        if(theCustomer == null) {
            throw new CustomerNotFoundException("le customer avec l'id donnée n'a pas été trouvé");
        }

        customerService.deleteCustomer(customerId);;

        return "le client avec l'id" + customerId + " a été supprimé";
    }

}
```

here is the drive link for those who want to test my application :

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Hko4iSjpR1qV7s1kfWVdLbotWzn1Cvx1

can someone help me please ?

Comment: Use a proxy like Fiddler to capture the exact requests and responses and look at the request. It is obviously invalid in some way (400 = "Bad Request"), but it'd be hard to tell in what way without seeing it.

Answer (score 3):

In the error stack trace you can see that the last row called of your code is

```
com.luv2code.springdemo.service.CustomerServiceRestClientImpl.getCustomer(CustomerServiceRestClientImpl.java:59)
```

When looking in that method i find this declared function body.

```
// make REST call
Customer theCustomer = restTemplate.getForObject(crmRestUrl + "/" + theId, 
                                      Customer.class);
```

400 is a status code, so restTemplate makes it's call correctly but 4xx means that the responding server says that the request is malformed or bad from the client (so its not the responding servers fault). So i start looking at the request. You are using two parameters, `theId` which is an input param and then the url `crmRestUrl`.

When looking up where these parameters are declared i find the following.

```
private String crmRestUrl;
```

i believe this is `null` and that might be your problem.

Comment: Hello,

I do not think that crmRestUrl is null because I put in my properties file the following line:crm.rest.url=http://localhost:8080/spring-crm-rest/api/customers    and i also put @Autowired
 public CustomerServiceRestClientImpl(RestTemplate theRestTemplate, 
          @Value("${crm.rest.url}") String theUrl) {
  restTemplate = theRestTemplate;
  crmRestUrl = theUrl;
    
  logger.info("Loaded property:  crm.rest.url=" + crmRestUrl);
 }

Comment: this method gets the url which is in my properties file and stores it in the crmRestUrl variable, so I don't think crmRestUrl is null

Comment: well your request to the second service is returning 400 which means client exception. It tells us that your request you are doing from service A is done the wrong way. So would start logging your request, and checking all your request parameters and the url.

Comment: i have given you all the information you need to debug/log/find your error.

Comment: I know the error comes from this line : Customer theCustomer = 
    restTemplate.getForObject(crmRestUrl + "/" + theId, 
            Customer.class);  I did some debugging and it still hangs here I also made some log one before the line mentioned and one after, the first which before before the line mentioned it is displayed well in my console while the second does not appear, which proves that the line that I mentioned you don't run. the problem is that I really can't find the solution, can't you help me please?

Comment: Then make a request to the service using postman, curl or any other tool and then compare the requests.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I was missing body with httpentity, was compiling fine but throws while running

```
 String uri=   "http://localhost:8063/api/"+templateId;
    try {
        res = restTemplate.exchange(
           uri , HttpMethod.GET,
                new HttpEntity<>( headers), DTO.class);
```

then changed to below code and worked fine

```
   String uri=   "http://localhost:8063/api/"+templateId;
    try {
        res = restTemplate.exchange(
           uri , HttpMethod.GET,
                new HttpEntity<>(**null**, headers), DTO.class);
```